# Rich tree structures with PHP

Tags: php, tree, structure, nodes

I'm finding it very difficult to find anything about creating maintanable, navigatable and verbose tree structures in PHP. I wanted to open it up to the SO community and see who's done what.

The way I can see creating this sort of structure is to have an object for every node, with a reference to the parent or child nodes. I've yet to put anything in code.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm looking for an object graph - a way to contain various objects in a tree context

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [new Datastructures in SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php) and the various [available iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)

Is that what your are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Maintainable site navigation is most easily stored in stored in a database.  With that being said, MySQL has a wonderful article entitled [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

I have previously mentioned the article on [this SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860118/how-do-you-generate-website-navigation/1860135#1860135).

Comment: I think he is looking for tree structures as in object graphs.